Trouble Overriding addNodes Method in Eclipse Milo's NodeManagementServices
I'm currently working on an OPC UA server using Eclipse Milo 0.6.12 and I've encountered a problem with overriding the addNodes method in my implementation of NodeManagementServices. Despite properly overriding the method in my ManagedNamespaceWithLifecycle class, the server continues to invoke the default addNodes method provided by Milo, rather than my custom implementation.
Here’s a snippet of my implementation:
@Override
public void addNodes(AddNodesContext context, List<AddNodesItem> nodesToAdd) {
    System.out.println("called");
    // Implementation details
}

I've ensured that the method signature exactly matches what’s defined in the interface and the class definitely implements NodeManagementServices. However, when I send a request to add a node from a client, it doesn't trigger the overridden method but goes to the default method instead.
Is there something specific that needs to be done to correctly register or acknowledge the overridden method in the server setup? Any advice or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!
I want my overridden addNodes method to be executed instead of the default method provided by Eclipse Milo.

Do you have a custom AddressSpaceFilter configured? Do the Nodes you're trying to add belong to your Namespace implementation according to the namespace index?

Thank you for your response. I haven't configured a custom AddressSpaceFilter, so it's using the default settings. Regarding the namespace index, the nodes I'm trying to add should indeed belong to my namespace as I've specified the correct namespace URI and index in their identifiers. I'll double-check the namespace indices to make sure they align with my implementation. Do you think this could be causing the method not to be called, or should I look into other potential configuration issues?

I am currently implementing the addNodes method based on the default server example provided by Eclipse Milo.

Other than a bug, the Nodes either not belonging to your Namespace or otherwise not being included by the AddressSpaceFilter seems most likely. It might be more appropriate to open a Discussion at https://github.com/eclipse/milo/discussions to further troubleshoot and share code.
